# How to connect NodeMcu ESp8266(lua) to Mosquitto MQTT Broker?

Tags: c++, arduino, esp8266, nodemcu

My problem is that I try to connect an NodeMcu ESP 8266(Lua) to a mosquitto mqtt broker. I create a mosquitto topic listener in console so i can test if it works, i send some message to that topic from another console and it shows them but when i try to do the same thing on the arduino it doesn't show any message:
`mosquitto_sub -v -t 'test/topic'`
this is how i created my server and this is how i sent the testing messages:
`mosquitto_pub -t 'test/topic' -m 'helloWorld'`.
This is the code that is use on the NodeMcu board:

It's the mqtt_esp8266 sketch example from PubSubClient library modified for my ip and wifi
i say some post on google that said about that firewall may have something to do with that and i deactivated it multiple times, with still no use

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>
// Update these with values suitable for your network.
const char* ssid = "310";
const char* password = "1234567890";
const char* mqtt_server = "192.168.0.114";
WiFiClient espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);
unsigned long lastMsg = 0;
#define MSG_BUFFER_SIZE (50)
char msg[MSG_BUFFER_SIZE];
int value = 0;

void setup_wifi() {

  delay(10);
  // We start by connecting to a WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }

  randomSeed(micros());

  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}

void callback(char* topic, byte* payload, unsigned int length) {
  Serial.print("Message arrived [");
  Serial.print(topic);
  Serial.print("] ");
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    Serial.print((char)payload[i]);
  }
  Serial.println();

  // Switch on the LED if an 1 was received as first character
  if ((char)payload[0] == '1') {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, LOW);   // Turn the LED on (Note that LOW is the voltage level
    // but actually the LED is on; this is because
    // it is active low on the ESP-01)
  } else {
    digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED, HIGH);  // Turn the LED off by making the voltage HIGH
  }

}

void reconnect() {
  // Loop until we're reconnected
  while (!client.connected()) {
    Serial.print("Attempting MQTT connection...");
    // Create a random client ID
    String clientId = "ESP8266Client-";
    clientId += String(random(0xffff), HEX);
    // Attempt to connect
    if (client.connect(clientId.c_str())) {
      Serial.println("connected");
      // Once connected, publish an announcement...
      client.publish("test/topic", "hello world");
      // ... and resubscribe
      client.subscribe("inTopic");
    } else {
      Serial.print("failed, rc=");
      Serial.print(client.state());
      Serial.println(" try again in 5 seconds");
      // Wait 5 seconds before retrying
      delay(5000);
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(BUILTIN_LED, OUTPUT);     // Initialize the BUILTIN_LED pin as an output
  Serial.begin(115200);
  setup_wifi();
  client.setServer(mqtt_server, 1883);
  client.setCallback(callback);
}

void loop() {
  if (!client.connected()) {
    reconnect();
  }
  client.loop();
  unsigned long now = millis();
  if (now - lastMsg > 2000) {
    lastMsg = now;
    ++value;
    snprintf (msg, MSG_BUFFER_SIZE, "hello world #%ld", value);
    Serial.print("Publish message: ");
    Serial.println(msg);
    client.publish("test/topic", msg);
  }
}
```

```
14:25:01.014 -> ........
14:25:05.270 -> WiFi connected
14:25:05.270 -> IP address: 
14:25:05.270 -> 192.168.0.101
14:25:05.270 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
14:25:15.261 -> Attempting MQTT connection...failed, rc=-2 try again in 5 seconds
```

this is the serial monitor output

i am out of ideas, i tried node-red too but still no succes

Comment: What if you change your server to `mqtt_server = "test.mosquitto.org"` to use a third-party test server? will it work?